# Chrome claims simple function is undefined

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I've made a little morse code translator in my free time, and just tried it out in Chrome for the first time. When the `translate()` function is called, Chrome throws `Uncaught TypeError: translate is not a function at HTMLInputElement.onclick (morse:28)` in my face. The other fuctions work as expected, and `translate()` can be called from the console without issue. In addition, it works perfectly in Firefox.

Relevant (I think) HTML:

```
<div id="mainspan">

    <form id="morseForm">
        <textarea id="morseInput" rows="8" cols="50"></textarea><br><br>

        <input type="radio" name="trans" id="mtt" value="morseToText"><label for="mtt">Morse &rarr; text</label><br>
        <input type="radio" name="trans" id="ttm" value="testToMorse"><label for="ttm">Text &rarr; morse</label><br>
        <input type="button" onclick="translate()" value="Translate"><br><br>

        <textarea id="morseOutput" rows="8" cols="50"></textarea><br>
    </form>

</div>
```

And the JS:

```
function translate() {
    if (document.getElementById("mtt").checked == true) {morseToText()};
    if (document.getElementById("ttm").checked == true) {textToMorse()};
}
```

Comment: wait... it doesn't say the function is undefined. You assumed that. :p It simply says it isn't a function.

Comment: It's impossible to answer as written, because we can't see where the javascript is included in the HTML document. Can you make a jsfiddle that demonstrates the error?

Comment: My guess is you have an `id="translate"` somewhere. Using that assumption, i'm able to recreate your error. https://jsfiddle.net/n0jsfuck/

Comment: You might also try [jsLint](http://www.jslint.com/), I'm assumeing it might just be a typo/missing `;`

Comment: a missing `;` hardly ever results in a syntax error

Comment: What does `console.log(translate)` show?

Comment: @KevinB - is that a really unfortunate "random" jsfiddle link? n0jsfuck!!

Comment: @JaromandaX i was thinking the same, lol.

Comment: I agree with @KevinB. The error indicates that _something_ is defined with the name `foo`, but that it isn't a function (e.g. boolean, string, ...). Elements that have an `id` attribute magically get assigned to a global variable with the name of their `id` value. Maybe you also have your JavaScript in an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/)? That would cause the `translate()` function to be defined but not globally. Since assigning a function to `onclick` inline in this manner uses the global scope, it would see the element instead of the function.

Comment: @SethHolladay the *magic* part is that even if it isn't in an IIFE, the id will still mangle it. :)

Comment: I suspect the `onClick` is expecting a function, not the returned value of the function. Try replacing `translate()` with `translate` instead.

Comment: It seems to be specific to the word `translate` ... change the `translate` in `function translate` and `onclick="translate()"` to `trans` and the problem goes away - oh, and it has nothing to do with having an element with id=translate either - see https://jsfiddle.net/n0jsfuck/1/

Comment: @char - that's not how on* attributes work - they expect a string which is effectively "eval'd" ... so `translate` wont execute the function, but `translate()` will :p

Comment: The issue also exists if you use `name` instead of `translate` ... I'm sure there are others.

Comment: Okay, I'm back! [Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/u2dudpxd/) a jsfiddle of the page. @AmericanUmlaut

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably an "unwanted feature" of Chrome, `translate` seems to have some "special meaning" event though it is usually undefined

```
<script>
  function translate () {
    alert('or nah');
  }
</script>
<button onclick="translate()">
  translate!
</button>
```

Doesn't work, however,

```
<script>
  function translate () {
    alert('or nah');
  }
  window.onload = function() {
    document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', translate);
  }
</script>
<button>
  translate!
</button>
```

works - essentially the same, but obviously not

simplest solutions

1. use addEventListener method to add the click event to the button, or
2. don't use the name `translate`

Comment: This seems to be right. Further, the JSFiddle that @dustinrichards made demonstrating the problem seems also to have an issue with JSFiddle not executing the Javascript in global space - the functions declared in there are all no longer visible when onclick handlers are fired, but changing them to the form window.functionName = function () {...} fixes that.