# Why cant I access my function inside html element

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

This should be real simple, trying to write a function that on the click of a button will change the text value of an html element. When using Chrome, the issue is I keep getting on click `translate is not a function`, it seems I do not have access to my function, however, on other browser, it's working as expected. Why?

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>The HTML5 Herald</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="description" content="The HTML5 Herald">
  <meta name="author" content="SitePoint">
  <style src="./src/moshestyles.css"></style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 id="title"></h1>
  <button onclick="translate('english')"> English </button>
  <button> Hebrew </button>
  <button> Spanish </button>
  <script>
    function translate(language) {
      let myTitle = document.getElementById("title")
      if (language === "english") {
        myTitle.innerHTML = "Hello Welcome to Blanks App"
      }
      if (language === "hebrew") {
        myTitle.innerHTML = "שלום הגעתם לאפליקציה של פלוני"
      }
      if (language === "spanish") {
        myTitle.innerHTML = "Hola, bienvenidos a la aplicación Blank"
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

## EDIT

Turns out that like people here pointed out "translate" is reserved, so renamed to `translateBlurg`. Although unfortuantely this *still* does not work on codesandbox even after attempting to set the function on the global window object `window.translateBlurg = translateBlurg` I am getting an error `translateBlurg`.
The question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41623913/chrome-claims-simple-function-is-undefined) is similar although I do not see an actual explanation for why that is the case there either.

## 2nd EDIT

I was able to run the function in codesandbox by declaring it in the window `window.translateBlurg = translateBlurg` this did not work if the function was in the script tag only when in a separate file.

Comment: Add this line after your function on codesandbox: `window.translate = translate;`

Comment: rename `translate`

Comment: @AndroidNoobie That's wrong. The function is only called when the button is clicked.

Comment: Is translate a reserved word?

Comment: The snippet currently works, can you try to reproduce the issue here?

Comment: It doesn't work for me, works for you?

Comment: @Kaddath what browser are you using ?

Comment: Works perfect on firefox, `translate` must be another of Chrome oddities, never heard of it being a JS reserved word

Comment: using Chrome Version 76.0.3809.132 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: I edit your question and it is working...

Comment: Tried on Edge and Chrome, working as expected on Edge, not in Chrome

Comment: yea don't do that.

Comment: people keep saying 'translate' is reserved. but I can't find any evidence of it being reserved, and I can use it without consequence. So can someone please provide evidence? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Keywords

Comment: Can't call it anything other than "a bug in Chrome". Copied & pasted it worked as expected in FF. Renaming `translate` to `translate1` made it work in Chrome, too.

Comment: you can use the name `translate` on chrome fine, fwiw. `function translate() { return 123 }` works just fine in every console I test it on.

Comment: More fun: with `onclick="console.log(translate)"`, it'll log `true`. On Chrome, that is, because on Firefox it'll log the function `translate`, as very well it should.

Answer (score -3):

Chorme and Mozilla Firefox uses p5 JS rendering engine in their browsers. And translate is not a Pure Javascript reserved keyword but its p5 js built-in method. That's why its conflicting. 
For Ref: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/p5-js-translate-function/

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>The HTML5 Herald</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="description" content="The HTML5 Herald">
  <meta name="author" content="SitePoint">
  <style src="./src/moshestyles.css"></style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 id="title"></h1>
  <button onClick="translate_function('english')"> English </button>
  <button> Hebrew </button>
  <button> Spanish </button>
  <script>
    function translate_function(language) {
    alert('Hello');
      let myTitle = document.getElementById("title")
      if (language === "english") {
        myTitle.innerHTML = "Hello Welcome to Moshe Finsons App"
      }
      if (language === "hebrew") {
        myTitle.innerHTML = "שלום הגעתם לאפליקציה של משה פינסון"
      }
      if (language === "spanish") {
        myTitle.innerHTML = "Hola, bienvenidos a la aplicación Moshe Finsons"
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If you can find a reference that shows that `translate` is a reserved keyword in JavaScript, I'm sure this answer would be upvoted more...

Comment: Chorme and Mozilla Firefox uses p5 JS rendering engine in their browsers. And translate is not a Pure Javascript reserved keyword but its p5 js built-in method. That's why its conflicting. 
For Ref: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/p5-js-translate-function/

Comment: Not sure why you're responding to me. [Edit] your question to include your justification. Better yet, add an answer with that information to the duplicate.

Comment: do you have a source for chrome and FF embedding / using p5.js? This seems unlikely to me, and google does not seem to provide any insight on it.

Answer (score -6):

The reason is, translate is a keyword. Refer the details [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_translate.asp)
To fix, you may rename the method name from *translate* to something else.

Comment: It's usually better to point to MDN for documentation, rather than w3schools.com, which has a rather fraught history. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/translate

Comment: But you can use HTML attribute names as JS variables just fine: `title`, `id`, `data`, `style`, etc.

Comment: `translate` is **not** a reserved word. this answer is completely false.

Comment: translate is also a predefined function by JS. [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_translate.asp) is the link.

Comment: @Code_Ninja that's a method of the interface `CanvasRenderingContext2D`

Comment: okay, I didn't knew about it. @Cid